# Problemas ao utilizar Dropzone.js em um formulário

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou querendo adicionar campos à um formulário que utiliza o Dropzone.js para fazer o upload de arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando adiciono os arquivos para upload, a tela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var Galerias = function () {
    
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        initForm: function() {

            Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
                clickable: ".dropzone-previews",
                parallelUploads: 100,
                maxFiles: 100,
                maxFilesize: 5, // mb
                init: function() {
                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                        // Create the remove button
                        var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn btn-xs red btn-block'>Excluir</button>");
                        
                        // Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
                        var _this = this;

                        // Listen to the click event
                        removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                          // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                          e.preventDefault();
                          e.stopPropagation();

                          // Remove the file preview.
                          _this.removeFile(file);
                          // If you want to the delete the file on the server as well,
                          // you can do the AJAX request here.
                        });

                        // Add the button to the file preview element.
                        file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
                    });
                }            
            }

        }
    };
}();
```

```css
/* The MIT License */
.dropzone,
.dropzone *,
.dropzone-previews,
.dropzone-previews * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropzone {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
  padding: 1em;
}
.dropzone.dz-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message,
.dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropzone.dz-clickable * {
  cursor: default;
}
.dropzone .dz-message {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.dropzone.dz-drag-hover {
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}
.dropzone.dz-started .dz-message {
  display: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 17px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview [data-dz-thumbnail],
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-file-preview [data-dz-thumbnail] {
  display: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-details {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ebebeb;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details img,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-details img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -28px;
  left: 3px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark {
  display: block;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark {
  display: block;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview:hover .dz-details img,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview:hover .dz-details img {
  display: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-mark {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-success-mark {
  color: #8cc657;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-mark {
  color: #ee162d;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  display: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #8cc657;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-processing .dz-progress,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-processing .dz-progress {
  display: block;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-message {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -20px;
  background: rgba(245,245,245,0.8);
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #800;
  min-width: 140px;
  max-width: 500px;
  z-index: 500;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview:hover.dz-error .dz-error-message,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview:hover.dz-error .dz-error-message {
  display: block;
}
.dropzone {
  border: 0;
  min-height: 360px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  padding: 0;
}
.dropzone-previews {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  min-height: 360px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  padding: 23px;
}
.dropzone .dz-default.dz-message {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url("../images/spritemap.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 428px;
  height: 123px;
  margin-left: -214px;
  margin-top: -61.5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5/1),(min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:138dpi),(min-resolution:1.5dppx) {
  .dropzone .dz-default.dz-message {
background-image: url("../images/spritemap@2x.png");
-webkit-background-size: 428px 406px;
-moz-background-size: 428px 406px;
background-size: 428px 406px;
  }
}
.dropzone .dz-default.dz-message span {
  display: none;
}
.dropzone.dz-square .dz-default.dz-message {
  background-position: 0 -123px;
  width: 268px;
  margin-left: -134px;
  height: 174px;
  margin-top: -87px;
}
.dropzone.dz-drag-hover .dz-message {
  opacity: 0.15;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=15)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=15);
}
.dropzone.dz-started .dz-message {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.dropzone .dz-preview,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
  font-size: 14px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview:hover .dz-details img,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-image-preview:hover .dz-details img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=10);
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-progress .dz-upload,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-progress .dz-upload {
  background: #ee1e2d;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-success-mark {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url("../images/spritemap.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5/1),(min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:138dpi),(min-resolution:1.5dppx) {
  .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
  .dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
  .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
  .dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-success-mark {
background-image: url("../images/spritemap@2x.png");
-webkit-background-size: 428px 406px;
-moz-background-size: 428px 406px;
background-size: 428px 406px;
  }
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark span,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-mark span,
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark span,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-success-mark span {
  display: none;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-mark {
  background-position: -268px -123px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-success-mark {
  background-position: -268px -163px;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload {
  -webkit-animation: loading 0.4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: loading 0.4s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: loading 0.4s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: loading 0.4s linear infinite;
  animation: loading 0.4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/spritemap.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0px -400px;
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5/1),(min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:138dpi),(min-resolution:1.5dppx) {
  .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload,
  .dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload {
background-image: url("../images/spritemap@2x.png");
-webkit-background-size: 428px 406px;
-moz-background-size: 428px 406px;
background-size: 428px 406px;
  }
}
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-progress,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-progress {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-error-message {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.dropzone .dz-preview:hover.dz-error .dz-error-message,
.dropzone-previews .dz-preview:hover.dz-error .dz-error-message {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.dropzone a.dz-remove,
.dropzone-previews a.dz-remove {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #eee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fafafa, #eee);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: 26px;
}
.dropzone a.dz-remove:hover,
.dropzone-previews a.dz-remove:hover {
  color: #666;
}
@-moz-keyframes loading {
  from {
background-position: 0 -400px;
  }
  to {
background-position: -7px -400px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  from {
background-position: 0 -400px;
  }
  to {
background-position: -7px -400px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes loading {
  from {
background-position: 0 -400px;
  }
  to {
background-position: -7px -400px;
  }
}
@keyframes loading {
  from {
background-position: 0 -400px;
  }
  to {
background-position: -7px -400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
     <div class="portlet-title">
      <div class="caption">
       <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Galeria
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="portlet-body form">
      <form role="form" action="#" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="gal_id" value="{$galeria.gal_id}">
       <div class="form-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
         <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
         Você tem alguns erros no formulário. Por favor, verifique abaixo.
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
         <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
         O formulário foi validado com sucesso! Aguarde.
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3">Ativo</label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" class="make-switch" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-on-text="SIM" data-off-text="NÃO" {if $galeria.gal_active == 1 or !$livre}checked{/if}>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3">Título <span class="required"> * </span></label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título" class="form-control required" minlength="2" maxlength="100" value="{$galeria.gal_title}">
         </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="form-section">Imagens</h3>
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
          <button type="submit" class="btn green-meadow">{if !$livre}Adicionar{else}Salvar{/if}</button>
          <a href="{$endereco}/galerias/listar" class="btn default">Cancelar</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Como posso fazer para que a mensagem "Drop files to upload" suma após os itens serem adicionados?

Comment: Eles deveriam ficar dentro do quadro cinza, parece que está sendo alinhado no final da tag <form>

Answer (score 2):

Defina nas configurações do Dropzone o item [previewTemplate](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewTemplate):

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    previewTemplate: document.querySelector('.dropzone-previews').innerHTML,
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Sem sucesso amigo. Li no site oficial sobre a opção, tentei colocar sem a classe (.) e com um id na div, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Hm, vi que existe o item `previewsContainer`, testa o seguinte `previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews'` ao invés do `previewTemplate` @MarcusDavid

Comment: Estava vendo essa opção agora @LúcioRubens. Adicionei essas duas opções: previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews", clickable: ".dropzone-previews". Vou editar o post com a imagem de como ficou

Comment: No seu css a altura da classe `.dropzone-previews` esta fixo: `height:100px`. Remove esta propriedade @MarcusDavid

Comment: Tive que mexer um pouco mais no `CSS`, esse do `height: 100px` era da altura da miniatura. Tive que mexer na classe `.dropzone` e adicionar a classe `.dropzone-previews` algumas configurações. O problema agora é que a mensagem fica "por cima" dos arquivos que irão ser enviados, impossibilitando o clique em alguns...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode modificar a mensagem da seguinte forma:

```
data: function(){ return {   dropzoneOptions: { dictDefaultMessage: '' }}}
```

Onde o `dictDefaultMessage` modifica sua mensagem, então é só definir como branco.